# Deleting children and father view is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm deleting father and his children, I'm using recursive, this's function:

```
function remove(idnodo) {
    
    let indexremove = data.findIndex(item => item.id === idnodo);
    if(indexremove>= 0) {
         
        let child = data.filter(item => item.idParent == idnodo);
        child.forEach(c => remove(c.id));    
                   
        data.splice(indexremove, 1);
    }
}
```

when this function is running and I clicked on any registry, for example:

```
Data 1
      data 2
      data 3
data 4
data 5
```

so if I clicked on `Data 1`, the children data 2 and data 3 is deleted, but the view is not updating, so I checked in colose and the array is updated but view not....

so I try to use setData() to update the data, but it not work, I try changed this line `data.splice(indexremove, 1);` for this `setdata( data.filter(item => item.id != indexremove ) );` so when I use setdata the view is updating but but but I'm deleting the wrong data, I mean If I try to delete `data 1` the registers data 4 and data 5 is deleteing.... but not data 1 and his children

what can I do ???

Comment: This might be related to updating the component/view state in React judged by the fact that data in the console changes. How is the new data propagated to the component ?

Comment: I'm using context, so I have one file to add, edit and delete, there I'm using usestate to stock the data,

Comment: but do you think that is better use setData of data.splice ???? to update the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your data is mutable. After removing the child items, re-assign data to a variable and set it via **setdata** method should work

```
function remove(idnodo) {    
    let updatedData = [];
    let indexremove = data.findIndex(item => item.id === idnodo);

    if(indexremove>= 0) {
        let child = data.filter(item => item.idParent == idnodo);
        child.forEach(c => remove(c.id));    
               
        data.splice(indexremove, 1);
    }
    updatedData = [...data];
    setdata({data: updatedData})
}
```